# Android YouTube API "An error occurred while initializing YouTube player"

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have an android app, which allows to play youtube video. I am using the latest YouTube API (1.2.1). I try it on a several devices within android version 4.0.4, 4.3, 4.4.4 or 5.0 and it works perfect (on every device is YouTube app version 10.-. But on one device, where is android 4.0.4 and YouTube app version 4.4.11 it does not work and get an error "An error occurred while initializing YouTube player". In documentation is written, that the minimal required version of YouTube app is 4.2.16. So I don't know, where is the problem.

Does somebody have an idea, what is wrong or how can I fix it?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Is that still working on other version except 4.0.4 ?. I got the same error and it is not working in any device anymore. It was working fine just recently in any device.

Comment: After actualization of YouTube app, it has started working fine. Then the phone was reset and the version of YouTube app was 4.2.16 again, but everything worked fine. It is curious.

Answer (score 52):

This issues coming in Android 11 and above version, due to **Package visibility filtering**

The limited app visibility affects the return results of methods that give information about other apps, such as queryIntentActivities(), getPackageInfo(), and getInstalledApplications(). The limited visibility also affects explicit interactions with other apps, such as starting another app's service.

For more info : https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility

Add the below lines of code into your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<queries>
   <intent>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START" />
   </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: for my app only the devices with android 11, I am facing the same issue but after adding these lines of code into the android manifest file it's work for me.

Comment: @Bilal This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Add these lines of code just above <application> tag in manifest.xml.
Though I still don't know why it didn't work without these lines and vice versa.
I followed a tutorial and got error while the tutorial guy had no issue playing a video.

Comment: @Bilal youtube apps can disable from samsung phones.. that case same error  shown, 
 what will do that case

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me now youtube player is working. By the way, I noticed that the queries tag should be above the application tag.

Answer (score 7):

Update your Android youtube app to the latest version and it will work for Sure!!

Answer (score 4):

I would never have thought to look in that location for the settings. It worked just as you said.

Here are the instructions for that less knowledge of the settings.

First, you need to go **Settings** -> **battery** -> **app launch** -> **YouTube.**

Now make disable the option **manage automatically.**

After disabling the above option, a popup will be shown.

Now make enable the option **Secondary Launch** (can be launched by other apps)

Answer (score 0):

**If someone still getting this error then**,

The problem is in the **layout file**, may be you defined the *fixed* ***height*** and ***width*** :

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:layout_width="123dp"
    android:layout_height="123dp" />
```

Replace height and width with "wrap_content" :

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score -3):

I  replaced targetSdkVersion =30 to  targetSdkVersion =26 and it's worked for me

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30`enter code here`
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.loopwiki.youtubeplayerexample"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}
```

Comment: That is just a terrible advice.