# Facing error "an error occurred while initializing you tube player" while i play video in my own created application

Tags: android, youtube, nokia, android-video-player

I am using Nokia 6 phone android version 7.1.2. I have created one mobile application and while I play you tube video in that application its showing **"an error occurred while initializing you tube player"** error.

Comment: an error occurred while initializing you tube player

Comment: Check your logcat. It will definitly show some errors.

Comment: Refer This SO Question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133874/android-youtube-api-an-error-occurred-while-initializing-youtube-player

Answer (score 0):

In that device go to playstore and update youtube app then install your application and try it.it will work.

In some case emulator is not work.so check with real device.

Comment: Checking with real device and also check above scenario.