# Why YouTube Player API does not work on Android 11?

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api, android-11

I tried the project explained on this YouTube video of how to play YouTube videos on Android apps:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Up9BjrIuoXY

I tried to play YouTube videos with devices using Android 9 and Android 10 and the videos are played correctly, but in Android 11 devices I received this message inside the YouTube video window:

*"An error occurred while initializing the YouTube player".*

This is the code of MainActivity.java:

```java
package com.example.youtube;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity {

    Button play_btn;
    YouTubePlayerView youtubePlayerView;
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener;

    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        youtubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtubeView);
        play_btn = findViewById(R.id.playvideo_btn);

        final android.app.Activity myActivity = this;

        onInitializedListener =new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo("Up9BjrIuoXY");
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                if (youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()) {
                    youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(myActivity, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
                } else {
                    String errorMessage = String.format(
                            getString(R.string.error_player), youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(myActivity, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };

        play_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                youtubePlayerView.initialize("AIzaSyZ2", onInitializedListener);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

YouTube app of the Android 11 devices is updated.

Hope somebody could help me. Thanks!

Comment: Have you search about this problem? - check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56395320/4092887) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32424164/4092887). These are the [search results on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=An+error+occurred+while+initializing+the+YouTube+player&rlz=1C1CHBF_esCO884CO884&oq=An+error+occurred+while+initializing+the+YouTube+player&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i64l3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - it will help if you can get more details of the error you got. Add the error details in your question by pressing [edit].

Comment: I had tried those solutions before my post without any success Mauricio Arias Olave. But thanks anyway, we have decided to use UniWebView since iOS support for this library is practically zero. Our project is targeted for iOS and Android and Google hasn't updated their YouTube API since ages. It uses UIWebView which Apple rejects from their store.

Comment: Misael L. I'm gladyou found an alternative. Please add an answer to your own question with the details you provided - due comments are temporal and are removed without notice - then, you solution will be missing for anyone who has the same problemd you had. Please see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Thank you.

Answer (score 53):

With the package visibility restrictions in Android 11 the SDK wont be able to find the Youtube service unless you add a reference to it to your manifest.

```
<queries>
   <intent>
     <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START" />
   </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: Big Thanks. Reference for others: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility

Comment: Updating this query is not working. YouTubeInitializationResult.SERVICE_INVALID @ivagarz

Comment: Wow, thanks! Where did you find this mystical "com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START"? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: hi @ivagarz Where is this documented?

Answer (score 29):

Update to Ivagarz's answer `queries` tag does not work under application tag So you have to add it outside `application` tag in manifest tag like this

```
<manifest
//permissions here
    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        </application>
        <queries>
        <intent>
         <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START"/>
        </intent>
        </queries>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: if you faced the error unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>" error Please refer to this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969917/how-to-fix-unexpected-element-queries-found-in-manifest-error

Answer (score 11):

This is happening because from Android 11 onwards (API 30+) Android hides all other apps and services which are not part of the core system apps/services by default, and you have to explicitly declare in your `Manifest.xml` that you need access to particular apps. From the docs, these are the only apps which you do NOT have to declare you need access to:

> - Your own app.
> - Certain system packages, such as the media provider, that implement
>   core Android functionality. Learn more about how to determine which
>   packages are visible automatically on the device that runs your app.
>   The app that installed your app.
> - Any app that launches an activity in
>   your app using the startActivityForResult() method, as described in
>   the guide about how to get a result from an activity.
> - Any app that
>   starts or binds to a service in your app.
> - Any app that accesses a
>   content provider in your app.
> - Any app that has a content provider,
>   where your app has been granted URI permissions to access that content
>   provider.
> - Any app that receives input from your app. This case applies
>   only when your app provides input as an input method editor.

You can declare that you need access in 3 ways:

> ...add the  element in your app's manifest file. Within the  element, specify the other apps [by package name](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility#package-name), [by intent signature](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility#intent-signature), or [by provider authority](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility#provider-authority)

In the case of YouTube it seems to make most sense to declare by package name, which looks like this (note - the package name is NOT `com.youtube`!):

```
<queries>
   <package android:name="com.google.android.youtube" />
</queries>
```

It appears that you need this even if you're just opening a YouTube web link, I think because if you have YouTube app installed, it registers any attempts to open something like `https://youtu.be/blah` as a request to the YouTube app, not the web browser.

Answer (score 6):

While specifically requesting the Youtube app works, I found it a bit too specific as the solution would break if a user installed an alternative player (not sure if there are any).
I think that the correct explanation is that the Youtube app not only filters for the https scheme, but also for the host "youtube.com" (which makes a lot of sense). So, by specifying the host as well, I got the Youtube app to be available to my app without a package specific declaration:

```
<queries>    
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data  android:scheme="https" android:host="youtube.com" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

BTW: When I tested, both "youtube.com" and "youtu.be" worked equally on both kinds of links. I still threw in both in my app to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Well. At last we have decided to use UniWebView Unity package and YouTube JavaScript API. Our project is targeted for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure which is the correct action, but both options worked for me in 2 different apps:

```
<queries>    
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data  android:scheme="https" android:host="youtube.com" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

and this one:

```
<queries>
   <intent>
     <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START" />
   </intent>
</queries>
```

I don't know which is 'better', or 'the correct' one to use.