# Android 11 YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi not working

Tags: youtube, initialization, android-youtube-api, android-11, youtubeplayer

I using `YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi` for Playing YouTube videos it was working good before Android 11 but when i installed System update to Android 11 it's stop working. I'm using OnePlus 8 device i also tested this code in Pixel 2 XL emulator but same error occur. Same code working on or before Android 10.

YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi version : YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.2.2.zip

Error is : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64740722/2481542), it's because of package visibility on Android 11. you need to add a proper "query" tag to your AndroidMonifest.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Zahra Jamshidi